# html5: how to avoid two divs partially overlapp?

Tags: html, css

I am using this template:
[w3schools template](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_col-s)

to design a simple online shop. It shall be divided into three vertical areas: left, middle and right. The left area is a kind of preview, which shows an image of a selected product. The middle area contains pictures of products: Whenever a product is "selected"  from this middle area - through mouse over (on a desktop) , this product shall be shown in the left "preview" area. The right area shall contain a table of all selected products.

Now I have the problem that the left and the middle area partially overlapp on a desktop laptop (the right area is not ready yet). I wouuld like to avoid this partiall overlapping. How can I achive this? Below is my css and the html:

```css
* { /*   @see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp */
  box-sizing: border-box; /*  makes sure that the padding and the border are included in the total width and height of the elements. */
}


/* For mobile phones: Always Design for Mobile First!*/
[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.productImage  > *{
   display :block;
}

 .productImage{
  float:left;
 }

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {   /* For tablets: */
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
  
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {   /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
  
 .tableImage{
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
  padding: 5px;
 }
 
 .productImage:hover{
  background-color:#ddd; 
 }
} 


/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.aside {
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

/* Style the footer */
.footer {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}


.chosenProductDetailsImage{  /** style for the product's detailed image */
 height:550px;
 width:400px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script src="js/onlineshop.js"></script> 
  <title>On-line shop</title>
 </head>
 <!-- Header -->
 <body>
       <div class="row">
      <div id="leftDiv" class="col-3 col-s-3">
   <img alt="" id="chosenProductDetailsImageId" class="chosenProductDetailsImage" src=""/>
      </div>  
   <div class="col-7 col-s-9">
   <div class ="productImage">
    <img src="images/NA823E08M-H11@6.jpg"  alt= "product NA823E08M" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="NA823E08M-H11@6"  onclick="setAddedToCart(this)"  name="addToCart" value="Summer light skirt"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">12,45 €</span></span>
   </div>
   <div class ="productImage">
    <img src="images/A0F21S00I-K11@7.jpg"  alt= "product A0F21S00I" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="A0F21S00I-K11@7"  onclick="setAddedToCart(this)"  name="addToCart" value="Summer jeans light"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">13,99 €</span></span>
   </div>
   <div class ="productImage">
    <img src="images/NA823F0VN-E11@7.jpg"  alt= "product NA823F0VN" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="NA823F0VN-E11@7" onclick="setAddedToCart(this)" name="addToCart" value="Light Body Skirt"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">8,00 €</span></span>
   </div>
   <div class ="productImage">
    <img src="images/AGA21S008-K11@5.jpg"  alt= "product AGA21S008" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="AGA21S008-K11@5" onclick="setAddedToCart(this)" name="addToCart" value="Summer jeans classic"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">7,99 €</span></span>
   </div>
   <div class="productImage">
    <img src="images/NX323F11F-E11@7.jpg"  alt= "product NX323F11F" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="NX323F11F-E11@7"  onclick="setAddedToCart(this)"  name="addToCart" value="Pijamma light"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">16,99 €</span></span>
   </div> 
   <div class="productImage">
    <img src="images/ARC21S002-C11@10.jpg"  alt= "product ARC21S002-C11@10" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ARC21S002-C11@10" onclick="setAddedToCart(this)" name = "addToCart" value = "Blue jeans classic"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">26,99 €</span></span>
   </div> 
   <div class="productImage">
    <img src="images/OU523H01C-E11@7.jpg"  alt= "product OU523H01C" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="OU523H01C-E11@7" onclick="setAddedToCart(this)" name = "addToCart" value = "Summer T-shirt"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">24,99 €</span></span>
   </div>
   <div class="productImage">
    <img src="images/IR221S001-K11@2.jpg"  alt= "product IR221S001-K11@2" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="IR221S001-K11@2" onclick="setAddedToCart(this)" name = "addToCart" value = "Blue jeans patched"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">27,99 €</span></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 col-s-12">
      <div class="aside">
        <h2>What?</h2>
        <p>Chania is a city on the island of Crete.</p>
        <h2>Where?</h2>
        <p>Crete is a Greek island in the Mediterranean Sea.</p>
        <h2>How?</h2>
        <p>You can reach Chania airport from all over Europe.</p>
      </div>
    </div> <!--  class = "col-3 col-s-12" -->
 </div> <!--  class="row" -->
 <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Media Query CSS Order & Change width Here `.chosenProductDetailsImage` `100%`

```css
* { /*   @see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp */
  box-sizing: border-box; /*  makes sure that the padding and the border are included in the total width and height of the elements. */
}


/* For mobile phones: Always Design for Mobile First!*/
[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.productImage  > *{
   display :block;
}

 .productImage{
  float:left;
 }



@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {   /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
  
 .tableImage{
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
  padding: 5px;
 }
 
 .productImage:hover{
  background-color:#ddd; 
 }
} 
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {   /* For tablets: */
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
  
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.aside {
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

/* Style the footer */
.footer {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}


.chosenProductDetailsImage{  /** style for the product's detailed image */
 height:550px;
 width:100%;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script src="js/onlineshop.js"></script> 
  <title>On-line shop</title>
 </head>
 <!-- Header -->
 <body>
       <div class="row">
      <div id="leftDiv" class="col-3 col-s-3">
   <img alt="" id="chosenProductDetailsImageId" class="chosenProductDetailsImage" src=""/>
      </div>  
   <div class="col-7 col-s-9">
   <div class ="productImage">
    <img src="images/NA823E08M-H11@6.jpg"  alt= "product NA823E08M" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="NA823E08M-H11@6"  onclick="setAddedToCart(this)"  name="addToCart" value="Summer light skirt"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">12,45 €</span></span>
   </div>
   <div class ="productImage">
    <img src="images/A0F21S00I-K11@7.jpg"  alt= "product A0F21S00I" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="A0F21S00I-K11@7"  onclick="setAddedToCart(this)"  name="addToCart" value="Summer jeans light"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">13,99 €</span></span>
   </div>
   <div class ="productImage">
    <img src="images/NA823F0VN-E11@7.jpg"  alt= "product NA823F0VN" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="NA823F0VN-E11@7" onclick="setAddedToCart(this)" name="addToCart" value="Light Body Skirt"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">8,00 €</span></span>
   </div>
   <div class ="productImage">
    <img src="images/AGA21S008-K11@5.jpg"  alt= "product AGA21S008" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="AGA21S008-K11@5" onclick="setAddedToCart(this)" name="addToCart" value="Summer jeans classic"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">7,99 €</span></span>
   </div>
   <div class="productImage">
    <img src="images/NX323F11F-E11@7.jpg"  alt= "product NX323F11F" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="NX323F11F-E11@7"  onclick="setAddedToCart(this)"  name="addToCart" value="Pijamma light"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">16,99 €</span></span>
   </div> 
   <div class="productImage">
    <img src="images/ARC21S002-C11@10.jpg"  alt= "product ARC21S002-C11@10" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ARC21S002-C11@10" onclick="setAddedToCart(this)" name = "addToCart" value = "Blue jeans classic"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">26,99 €</span></span>
   </div> 
   <div class="productImage">
    <img src="images/OU523H01C-E11@7.jpg"  alt= "product OU523H01C" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="OU523H01C-E11@7" onclick="setAddedToCart(this)" name = "addToCart" value = "Summer T-shirt"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">24,99 €</span></span>
   </div>
   <div class="productImage">
    <img src="images/IR221S001-K11@2.jpg"  alt= "product IR221S001-K11@2" class="tableImage" onmouseout = "hideDetailImage();" onmouseover="showDetailImage(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="IR221S001-K11@2" onclick="setAddedToCart(this)" name = "addToCart" value = "Blue jeans patched"/> 
    <span class="addToCartSpan">Add to Cart</span>
    <span class="priceAb">ab <span class="price">27,99 €</span></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 col-s-12">
      <div class="aside">
        <h2>What?</h2>
        <p>Chania is a city on the island of Crete.</p>
        <h2>Where?</h2>
        <p>Crete is a Greek island in the Mediterranean Sea.</p>
        <h2>How?</h2>
        <p>You can reach Chania airport from all over Europe.</p>
      </div>
    </div> <!--  class = "col-3 col-s-12" -->
 </div> <!--  class="row" -->
 <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it and let you know  later today or tomoorow!